# Make wix uninstall installed version of product instead of stopping install

Tags: wix, windows-installer

If I build my installer and install it everything works.  If I build a new version of it 5 mins later and try to overwrite the existing install I get the following...

Essentially I'd like and installer in Wix that uninstalls any existing version of our app (newer or older) and installs our.  We have to rapidly upgrade our app in some cases so not having to manually remove the program in Add/Remove programs would be nice.

[image]

Comment: Your MSI is authored as a Minor Upgrade which requires an EXE to pass the REINSTALLMODE and REINSTALL properties.  A Major Upgrade behaves the way you request and is described by Phil below.

Answer (score 3):

Use the WiX MajorUpgrade element. Increase the product version somewhere in the first three fields, use a new ProductCode, keep thee same UpgradeCode and it should all just do the upgrade, uninstalling the old product and installing the new one. Using after=InstallIntialize is perhaps the safest place to sequence the upgrade.